# How does Garen's Courage interact with "Legendary Armor"?

Tags: league-of-legends

If you look at the champion [Garen](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Garen) he has the ability [Courage](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/ability/courage-256) and its passive is: *Garen's Armor and Magic Resistance are permanently increased by 20% of bonus Armor and Magic Resistance.*

In the defense tree you have the talent [Legendary Armor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Armor_%28Season_Three_Mastery%29) which gives :*Increases bonus armor and magic resistance by 5%.*

How is this bonus percentage calculated ? Does it count as 25% of bonus armor, first adds bonus 20 % and then bonus 5% or first the 5% bonus and then the 20% bonus?

Comment: I can't say for sure because I haven't tested anything, but multiplying those bonuses separate from each other would leave the mechanic open for abuse. Usually in games the total flat bonus is added first, and then the amount is multiplied by the total percentage bonus (25% in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the two percentages multiply.  When I tested it with 1 thornmail, as well as the mastery, I had 127 bonus armor.  This is a 27% increase, not just 25%. Again, with two thornmails I had 254 bonus armor, for a 27% increase.

Strangely, 120% * 105% (1.2 * 1.05) only adds up to 126%, or a 26 percent increase.  I'm still not sure where that extra 1% came from.

Answer (score 0):

It multiples.

It will be something like this - Bonus Armor x (20%+5%)

From [LoL Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Garen/Ability_Details):

> Courage passively grants Garen increased armor and magic resistance
>   equal to a percentage of his *bonus armor and magic resist (from items,
>   runes or **masteries**)*. When activated, Courage is a self-target ability
>   that places a shield buff on Garen, reducing all incoming damage and
>   incoming crowd control by a percentage for a short duration.